# Is there a way to make Apache follow symlinks for the header content-type?

Tags: apache-2.2, symbolic-link

If I serve a file named `image.jpg` the header content-type is sent as `image/jpeg`, but if I make a softlink named `image` that points to `image.jpg` the content-type is sent as `text/plain`.

Is there a way to send the same content type as if it were reading the original file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content-type is determined by the mappings in the MIME-Magic file supplied with apache.
This has a mapping for *.jpg to image/jpeg.

You can force the content-type inside a container, like so:

```
<Location /URI/of/images>
   ForceType image/jpeg
</Location>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#forcetype

Comment: Thanks! But not all the images are jpeg. Although if I can't find a solution I guess I could make 3 directories for png/gif/jpg and iterate them with RewriteRule. But I would need to change the code that generates the symlinks and I would want to avoid that.

Comment: If there are specific filetypes, you can add a <FilesMatch> block for each of the real locations (which you must provide access to regardless, since the files are symlinked)

Comment: The problem is that the images and symlinks are generated dynamically so that wouldn't be practical.

Comment: In the other hand I just need to return the Content-Type of an image, it actually doesn't matter the exact type, so I guess ForceType is going to be enough.