# Apache2: Use target name of symlink for Content-Type mapping

Tags: apache-2.2, symbolic-link

I am working on a web application that need to serve a number of continuously updated documents at static URLs, but the Content-Type of the documents differs (it's either JPEG or SVG). If the document is a symbolic link, the file at the end of the link has the correct file extension for MIME type mapping, but I have not been able to tell if it is possible to get Apache to follow the link before looking the extension up in the MIME table.

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/363358) asks the same thing, but the workaround provided doesn't work for me, as browsers do not autodetect SVG if I serve image/jpeg (they do autodetect GIF and PNG), so I need a proper MIME type.

Normally, I would use .meta files and [mod_cern_meta](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cern_meta.html) for this, but my target Linux distributions (Fedora 19/20, RHEL 7) does not come with this, and I would like to avoid having to supply it myself. I don't think I can use mod_headers, since it would require me to rewrite the entire .htaccess file (the files are changed on an individual basis), nor mod_asis, as the data files themselves are generated using a third-party tool.

**Edit**: I am working around this by writing my files as type-maps (with one entry only), pointing to the actual resource and listing its Content-Type. It means having to write extra files, but so would using mod_meta. Works well enough for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried [mod_mime_magic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime_magic.html)? with this module enabled, apache can guess the content type the same way "file" command does and will set the content-type header correctly.

Checking the default configuration for a centos httpd installation, mod_mime_magic seems to be enabled by default and the content-type is set correctly when (for example) the request targets a symlink (namely "aaaa") for a, let's say, .png file.

Also, make sure you have [followsymlinks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) option enabled for the root directory containing the symbolic links (or just enable it for the entire documentroot)

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root       10 Jan 15 16:27 aaa -> pgid35.png
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   229727 Jan 15 16:26 pgid35.png


HEAD http://localhost/tt/aaa
200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 13:27:30 GMT
[...]
Content-Length: 229727
Content-Type: image/png                      <<<--- [[bullseye]]
Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 13:26:47 GMT
[...]
```

I'm going to include for brevity some configuration hints for apache httpd to make mime magic work:

```
#assuming the module folder is linked within apache root config dir as 'modules'
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
#define the magic file containing patterns for identifying file types
MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
#the system magic file normally contains more patterns than 
#the default http magic file
#centos magic file install path:
#MIMEMagicFile /usr/share/misc/magic
#do follow the symlinks if you are using them
<Directory />
Options FollowSymlinks
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It seems that I would have to enable it for the entire server, not only just for the directory where I have the troublesome files (or, for that matter, the files themselves), so I'm not sure if it will work, but I will give it a shot at least.

Answer (score 0):

How about making your static URLs not point directly to the documents, but to a simple script that sets the correct Content-Type header and then streams the document?

```
<?php
    $filename = "path/to/your/file";

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
    $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $filename); 
    finfo_close($finfo);

    header("Content-Type: ".$mimetype );
    echo readfile($filename);
?>
```